# How to create a new dash panel for my program?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, application-development, lenses

I am developing a new AI chatbot assistant that i want to embed in the dash menu panel in unity. where do i go into the .* files to edit / create this? also can i code menus in python at all? 
basically i am wanting to give the chatbot access to find files, applications, webpage links email address ect from what is found in unity. basically like the new siri for iphone.
any help would be great.

the project i am working on is called ButlerBot which i am hosting off github.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Dash applications are called "lenses". You can find the API information here:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/Lenses

Feel free to ask implementation/programming questions on the [ayatana mailing list](https://launchpad.net/~ayatana-dev).

Comment: awesome thanks! hopefully once it is up and fully functional it will be a really cool AI program for ubuntu! the program is still in alpha so i has a long way to go, but it has a good start.